# Surprising instantiation pattern - new keyword used on a wrapper function

Tags: javascript, new-operator, instantiation

Working on `Paper.js` library, I discovered in the codebase, a way to instantiate a class that I never used before. It is used for example [here](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/blob/ef7beacd8b0ce5a9b872d16b1a08e8c381172064/src/item/Shape.js#L429-L434) to instantiate the `Shape` class.
This instantiation pattern can be simplified to this: given a `Ball` class and a `createBall()` method that instantiate it:

```
function Ball() {}
function createBall() {return new Ball()}
```

We can, of course, get a ball instance by calling:

```
var ball = createBall();
```

But more surprinsingly, we can also get a ball instance by calling (notice the `new` keyword):

```
var ball = new createBall();
```

Or as a more abstract way:

```
var ball = new function() {return new Ball()};
```

Since `createBall()` returns a `Ball` instance, it gives the impression that we are instantiating the `Ball` class by using `new` keyword on an instance of it.

But as we can see in the following code, this is not something allowed and throws an error if we do it manually:

```
var ball1 = new Ball();
var ball2 = new ball1();
// error: ball1 is not a constructor
```

Can someone explain me what is the logic behind that ?

Here is a comparative example of different instantiation methods:

```js
// Class
function Ball() {}

// Method creating an instance of the class
function createBall() {
  // Instantiate the class
  var ball = new Ball();
  // Return the instance
  return ball;
}

// Expected: instantiating directly works
var ball1 = new Ball();
console.log('ball1', ball1 instanceof Ball); // outputs true

// Expected: instantiating through the creation method works
var ball2 = createBall();
console.log('ball2', ball2 instanceof Ball); // outputs true

// Unexpected: instantiating like this surprisingly works
var ball3 = new createBall();
console.log('ball3', ball3 instanceof Ball); // outputs true

// Expected: instantiating like this throws an error
var ball4 = new ball1();
// error: ball1 is not a constructor
```

### Edit

After reading @robert-zigmond comment, I discovered another misleading case:

```js
function Dog() {}

function Ball() {
  return new Dog();
}

var instance = new Ball();

console.log('is instance a Ball ?', instance instanceof Ball); // false
console.log('is instance a Dog ?', instance instanceof Dog); // true
```

Comment: `ball1` isn't even a function, so that's why you get the error there. I didn't realise JS had a specific "not a constructor" error message, I guess it does that if you try to call something that's not a function using the `new` keyword, but it's misleading imo. *any* function can be called using the `new` operator - essentially that makes it construct a new object, which is taken as the `this` reference for the function, and returns it (but only if the function doesn't return an object already - if it does, the constructed object is thrown away).

Comment: Thanks, I understand better how it work now. I edited my question to include another example which can be misleading, based on what you explained.

Comment: I guess the confusing part of the bit you've added is that `instance` is not an instance of `Ball`, despite being constructed with `new Ball()`. That's because, as I said, when a function is called with `new`, it constructs an object, but only returns that if the "ordinary" return  value would not be an object. Here it *does* return an object, which is itself an instance of `Dog`, so the `new` operator doesn't really do anything. (That's not strictly true, but I don't think you can observe any of the differences here. I could be wrong though.)

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#Description

Comment: Yes, your explanation was clear and documentation makes it even clearer, thanks, I get it now. Do you want to post your comment as an answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: I'd be happy to do so, the main reason I only posted it as a comment to start with was that I thought you were asking more, and I was only commenting on part of your question? (Also as you saw I was and still am a little unsure as to what exactly causes the "not a constructor" error message.)

Comment: Actually, the only thing I didn't understood was how `new function() {return new Ball()}` syntax worked internally and I think your explanation + the documentation seems to answer it pretty well

Comment: @robin objects got two internal properties, `[[Call]]` and `[[Construct]]`, which are invoked on `fn()` or `new fn()`. A function has both properties, a plain object doesnt have any of those, if `[[Call]]` doesnt exist it says "fn is not a function", if `[[Construct]]` doesnt exist it says "fn is not a constructor"

Comment: @JonasWilms thanks for the explanation. Although I'm now curious how an object could end up with `[[Call]]` but not `[[Construct]]`. (It seems these are purely internal properties which can't be added via JS code?) @sasensi I've expanded a little on my comments above and put as an answer, as you requested :)

Comment: @RobinZigmond actually it can't. You could however create a `Proxy` that has a "call" but no "construct" trap. https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#function-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ball1` isn't even a function, so that's why you get the error there.

Any function in Javascript can be called using the new operator - essentially that makes it construct a new object, which is taken as the `this` reference for the function, and returns it (but only if the function doesn't return an object already - if it does, the constructed object is thrown away).

See here for exactly what the `new` operator does: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#Description

Your "other misleading case" does seem confusing at first, because `instance` is defined as `new Ball()` yet but `instance instanceof Ball` returns `false`. This is because, as I said above, the "constructor function" only returns the newly-constructed object if it otherwise returns a value which isn't an object at all. In most functions designed to be used as constructors, there is actually no explicit return value - so the return value is implicitly `undefined`, and so the newly-constructed object is returned.

But in this example, the function would otherwise return an object, which is an instance of `Dog` - so this object ends up as `instance`. Although created through `new Ball()`, this was somewhat indirect, it was *really* created by calling `new Dog()`, and thus `Dog.prototype` is in its prototype chain, and not `Ball.prototype`. This explains the behaviour of the `instanceof` operator that you observed.

Answer (score 1):

when `new Function` is called

1. A new object is created, inheriting from Function.prototype
2. the constructor is called and this is bound to the new object that first step created.
3. if nothing returned ,that this object will be returned or you can return a new object like your example

`function createBall() {
      console.log('origin this', this);
      return new Ball();
    }`

when `new createBall()` is called, it create a new object that inheriting from createFoo.prototype `this`, if nothing returned, then this object become the result of `new createBall()` but here you return a `new Ball()`, so the `this` object changed to `new Foo()` and returned